# Express response includes deleted key from Typescript array

Tags: typescript, express, ramda.js

I am having difficulty removing the `assetId` key from every element in my array.

```
type Video = {
  assetId?: string
  description: string
  publishedDate: string
  slug: string
  title: string
  uuid: string
}

const list = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, _: NextFunction) => {
  const videos = (await findVideos()) as Video[]
  const rVideos = R.forEach(R.dissoc('assetId'))(videos)
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok', count: videos.length, data: { rVideos } })
})
```

This does not work as the JSON body response is a list of `Video` that **still contain assetId**.

Here is another attempt:

```
const list = asyncHandler(async (req: Request, res: Response, _: NextFunction) => {
  const videos = (await findVideos()) as Video[]
  const rVideo = videos[0]
  delete rVideo['assetId']
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'ok', count: videos.length, data: { rVideo } })
})
```

Even still, the response contains a single video **that has assetId in it!**

In fact, I cannot even figure out how to remove an object key (`assetId`) for an Express response.

Comment: This is rather misterious. Is your code reloaded properly? Both ramda dissoc and `delete` should do the job according to your examples.

Comment: Could the response be cached in browser?

Comment: Yes, it's hot auto-reloading, and there is no cache in Postman.

Comment: it's mighty weird. but most likely typescript has nothing to do with it, that's what I can say for sure (99%) : )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that functions in Ramda never mutate the original data structures, so `R.forEach` is intended to iterate over the array and run some side-effecting function for each element, then return *the original* array.

Similarly, `R.dissoc` doesn't mutate the original object. It instead creates a new object without the key. So this new object is effectively discarded when run within `R.forEach`.

Try changing your example from:

```
R.forEach(R.dissoc('assetId'))(videos)
```

to:

```
R.map(R.dissoc('assetId'), videos)
```

Utilising `R.map` will produce and return a new array with the modified objects, rather than the original array.